# Restoring previous active window when active window closes

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

In OS/X 10.11 (EL CAPITAN): How do you make the previous app window the active app? For example, if I open Excel, then open Word, then open another Excel window, when I close the last (active) Excel window, I want to go back to the Word window as active, but OS/X makes the first Excel window active rather than the Word Window.

Answer (score 0):

That's because macOS isn't Windows. ;)

macOS is "application centric" not "window centric".

When you open that second Excel window, the Excel app becomes the active (front-most) application again. When you close a window in an app, the next window in its stack becomes the active window. If the app has no more windows, it's still the active app, there just isn't an active window.

This is because in macOS, the application's interface (menu bar, keyboard shortcuts, etc.) follow the active app—they aren't attached to windows, as they are in Windows, which is, by the way, how "Windows" got its name.

So what you don't want is to close a window and have all of your commands disappear on you, which is what would happen if the OS switched apps when you closed that most recent Excel window. Once you open or activate a macOS app, it stays the active app (along with all of its windows) until you Quit it or explicitly switch apps (by, say, clicking on the window of another app).